# From tuple's list to dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

So I have a question about creating dataframes of these types of lists.
I'm working with a dataset that resembles the mentioned example (although much larger).

```
data = [("A", (1, 2, 3)), ("B", (5, 7, 9)), ("C", (2, 4, 6))]
```

I've tried to make it look like a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A  B  C
1  5  2
2  7  4
3  9  6
```

I've explored the usage of

```
pd.DataFrame()
```

But it didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Convert list to a dict first: `pd.DataFrame(dict(data))`

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your data to `pd.DataFrame`, then use `set_index` method to set the index to the letters in each tuple, then transpose the dataframe and use the `explode` method to explode the inner tuples to separate rows. Then use `reset_index` and `rename_axis` methods to get the desired outcome.

```
data = [("A", (1, 2, 3)), ("B", (5, 7, 9)), ("C", (2, 4, 6))]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(0).T.explode(['A','B','C']).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns={0:None})
```

Another option is to use `apply(pd.Series)` and transpose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(0)[1].apply(pd.Series).T
```

Yet another way. You can separate names from data using `zip` and cast to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
idx, data = zip(*data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx).T
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  5  2
1  2  7  4
2  3  9  6
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way but you can convert your data into a `dict` and then to a `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [("A", (1, 2, 3)), ("B", (5, 7, 9)), ("C", (2, 4, 6))]

# convert to dictionary then to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(data))
```